# Exchange 2010 HELO header change

Tags: smtp, exchange-2010, fqdn

I couldn't find any appropriate step by step guide for changing HELO header values in Exchange 2010.

The problem is that the server doesn't allow changing the Default FQDN in: 
EMC -> Server configuration -> Hub transport -> Receive Connectors -> Default entry.
The problem comes from the reason it is Default.
I've read that I have to use Power Shell to change it.
If someone knows the correct commands to change this in Exchange 2010 I'd be rather thankful for this major help.

Regards!

Comment: `The first problem is that the server doesn't allow changing the Default FQDN in: EMC -> Server configuration -> Hub transport -> Receive Connectors -> Default entry. The problem comes from the reason it is Default` - I don't understand what you're saying. You can just type whatever you need into the provided field.

Comment: I could do that but the server won't let me apply the change in the field. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[To quote the product owner](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125159(v=exchg.141).aspx):

> Don't modify the FQDN value on the default Receive connector Default  that's automatically created on Hub Transport servers. If you have multiple Hub Transport servers in your Exchange organization and you change the FQDN value on the Default  Receive connector, internal mail flow between Hub Transport servers fails.

If you need to present a custom EHLO FQDN to external senders, create a new Receive Connector for inbound emails from the internet.

Or, preferably, deploy an Edge Transport server

Comment: Adding a new connector and disabling Exchange authentication removes TLS support from the setup.